# I can't use toDouble() method with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am new to kotlin and I am trying an execise.
I want to calculate the tip as % of the cost of the service.I enter my cost of service in an EditText... so far so good.

now I want to convert this the value I entered to double, which the datatype I need for my calculation.

this is my code:

```
package com.example.tiptime2

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.tiptime2.databinding.ActivityMainBinding

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        binding.calculate.setOnClickListener { calculateTip() }
    }
    fun calculateTip(){
        val myTextString= binding.costOfService.text.toString()
        val myCost = myTextString.toString()
        val cost = myCost.toDouble()
    }
}
```

androidStudio doesn't recognize toDouble()
why??

Comment: can you edit your question and post the error you are getting which is being shown.

Comment: additional to the error message can you also post what myCost contents? and why do you convert this two times to string (-> myTextString / myCost)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you explicit define variables type for debugging

```
fun calculateTip() {
    val costText: String = binding.costOfService.text.toString()
    val cost: Double = costText.toDouble()
}
```

> Still your code looks valid!

Answer (score 0):

You're casting to `.toString()` twice and you need to update the data-binding. Roughly alike:

```
val cost = Double.parseDouble(binding.costOfService.text.toString())

// some calculations

binding.costOfService.setText(String.valueOf(cost))
```

Instead of handling single values, it's common to bind a view-model, which has all of them.

Comment: It shouldn’t be necessary to resort to using the Java primitive wrapper classes, right? I don’t see why `toDouble()` shouldn’t be recognized.